# Ошибка при подключении к сайту

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Браузер Chroom выделяет, что мой сайт ненадёжный и помечает, как вредоносный. Как устранить проблему? Из-за чего потенциально может появиться такое уведомление ?

Comment: У вас нет ssl-сертификата скорее всего либо истек срок его действия, подключение идет по http. Поэтому и ругается

Comment: "Браузер Chroom"  --- Не грусти - похрусти!  %))

Comment: А так да, надо ssl сертификат ставить. Но если это какая-то сайт-визитка - то можно и забить

Comment: То есть, если я собираю данные с участников и не имею сертификат, то сайт будет помечаться, как вредоносный?

Comment: может ваш сайт имеет адрес с `https:`, но по факту там `http:`, или расположен на хостинге, на котором замечено много небезопасных сайтов. А то, что вы собираете персональные данные в небезопасном режиме - вообще за гранью совести.

Answer (score 0):

Если на сайте с адресом http подгружаются сторонние скрипты с адресов https, или наоборот, то браузеры могут помечать сайт как потенциально ненадежный.

Также может предупреждать Касперский

Исправьте вручную все адреса загружаемых скриптов на http, а иногда можно писать так:

```
...src="//anysite.com/js/file.js"
...href="//anysite.com/css/file.css"
```